Laravel "Page has expired due to inactivity" Error Only in Docker, Works Fine in XAMPP (htdocs)
'm facing an issue where my Laravel application works perfectly when running on a local XAMPP setup (htdocs), but when I try to run the same project inside a Docker container, I encounter the error "The page has expired due to inactivity. Please refresh and try again." during login. This error doesn't appear in the XAMPP setup, and the login process works smoothly there.

Laravel version: "laravel/framework": "5.5.43"
PHP version:      "php": ">=7.0.0",
Session driver: file (default)
CSRF token included: Yes, I have the {{ csrf_field() }} in my form.



Verify session storage configuration:
docker exec -it <container_name> bash 
chmod -R 755 storage/framework/sessions 
chown -R www-data:www-data storage/framework/sessions
